# CSS: text-decoration:none; works in Firefox, does not work in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, text-decorations

I'm developing a footer in an HTML file ( simplified, included below ).  I have two links, with images on the left called:

- footer1
- footer2

In Firefox 13 the blue line of the hyperlink does NOT appear around these two image/links, as desired.  In IE 8, the blue line does and stubornly refuses to go away despite including the css ( see file below ):

```
 #footer1 a{text-decoration:none;}
```

I would like to make the blue links for the links in the left two image/links go away and keep the text decoration in my other links.

Thanks much in advance for any help.

Steve

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Text Decoration Will Not Disappear In Two Left Images In IE 8</title>
    <style type ="text/css">
    #footer
    {
        background-image:url('../images/bg-texture.gif');
        padding: 20px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size:8pt;
    }
    #footer ul, li 
    {
        display: inline;
        float:left;
        list-style-type: none;
        vertical-align:top;
        text-align:left;
    }


    #footer1 {margin-right:10%;margin-left:5%;}
    #footer1 a{text-decoration:none;}
    #footer2{margin-right:10%;}
    #footer3{margin-right:10%;}
    #footer4{margin-right:10%;}
    #footer5{margin-right:10%;}

    </style>
</head>

    <body>

            <!-- The Footer -->
            <ul id="footer">
                <li id="footer1"><a href="http://slashdot.org"> <img alt="" src="files/doc.gif"/></a></li>
                <li id="footer2"><a href="http://google.com"><img alt="" src="files/noaa.gif"/></a></li>
                <li id="footer4"><a href="http://slashdot.org/">Right Link 1</a></li>
                <li id="footer5"><a href="http://google.com">Right Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To remove the border from images you should do

```
a img { border: 0 }
```

and that won't affect your text links

Comment: How is it different from Niels answer?

Comment: @SubirAdhikari The only difference is the time of answer :) I've answered at `14:41`, Neils at `14:42`

Comment: I thought duplicate answers are not welcome!! When you check the same answer already posted, you should vote it up.

Answer (score 2):

The blue around images that are a link is a border. So set this and it should be fine:

```
a img
{
border:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following selector:

div * p

matches a P element that is a grandchild or later descendant of a DIV element. Note the white space on either side of the "*" is not part of the universal selector; the white space is a combinator indicating that the DIV must be the ancestor of some element, and that that element must be an ancestor of the P.

Hence,

try

```
#footer1 * a{text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: Actually, you do not have text. So you need a border off for the IMG